how can i use mongodb compass offline ,i keep getting 'connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017'
please i've been stucked at this for hours ,on a norm if i want to use mongodb compass offline i just download it , this the file i downloaded 
this the error each time i try to connect ,please how can i go about thisut this

Offline functionality of compass is very limited unless you have a mongodb server running locally

@AlexBlex thats what i want to  do , i want to run it locally but dont know how

Did you start a local MongoDB server?

how can i start it PLEASE @AKX

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

To clarify: MongoDB Compass is a GUI for poking at a MongoDB server (whether local or remote); the server (that stores your data) is a separate product.

Your question is not about programming but about installation/administration of a DB. Consider https://dba.stackexchange.com/ instead.

download mongodb compass exe then download mongodb community msi seperately,install both when installing mongo community make sure you un-check install mongo compass

According to the error message you don't have a running MongoDB instance or it's port is changed. Please check in the task manager whether you have a running task mongod.
In case not, here is how you start it:
Open the command prompt and navigate to your Mongo server installation directory (by default it is C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server<Version>\bin) like this:
cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\<Version>\bin

Then enter the following:
mongod

If you have installed Mongo server it should run it at the default port. In case you have a running mongod end that task and start it again with my instructions.
Update
In case you already stored data on mongod or want to change default port:
mongod --dbpath <path\to\db> --port <number>

On Windows data resides by default on C:\data\db.
Update 2
According to your comment you don't have installed Mongo Server. Here is the download link:
https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community

the thing is that i dont see mongodb in my program file after installing compass
